# Arduino uno weird behavior on a simple counter program

Tags: arduino-uno

So I just got my first Arduino Uno board and the output on the serial monitor doesn't make sense to me. For this code

```
int counter = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  counter++;
  Serial.println(counter);
  delay(1);
}
```

I'm expecting to see an increment once every 1ms. But what I see from the console is odd[image]

First, I'm expecting to see the timestamp like this: 27.270, 27.271, 27.272...
Second, from 27.301 to 27.334, I only saw the counter increase by 7 instead of ~30.

Answer (score 5):

If you do something like

```cpp
Serial.println(580);
```

that is 5 characters printed (3 digits, then CR and LF to end the
line). Each character takes ten bits worth of transmission time (one
start bit, 8 data bits and one stop bit). The whole message is then
50-bit long on the serial line. At 9600 bits per second, this takes
about 5.2 milliseconds.

Note that the PC seems to be buffering the data, which is displayed in
batches, each batch having a single timestamp. Thus you see that, on
**average** there are 5.2 ms between increments.

Comment: So is there a quick fix to this?

Comment: @GotYaLoot: Fix for what? If the problem is, as stated in the question, “_the output [...] doesn't make sense to me_”, the fix is simply to understand this answer. Is there another problem that would need to be fixed?

Comment: I want the serial monitor show something like:
time 0.001 counter=1
time 0.002 counter=2
time 0.003 counter=3

Comment: How are you expecting to see a printout every ms when it takes over 5ms to print one line? Also as stated above, when working with serial communication to a PC, there are multiple buffers involved along with the non-real time os that your PC is running. This means there is no way to get ms precision of printed lines with this setup. Its going to be really hard for anyone to give much advise since we have no idea what you are trying to accomplish(big picture wise).

Comment: If you increase the baud rate from 9600 to 115200 you will see much faster prints, but you are still at the mercy of the the serial buffers and OS on your pc.

Comment: If it takes half an hour to bake a cake, setting a timer for 1 second after you bake the cake, will not make cakes appear every second.